# Getting Value from listview from Mobile Service DataSource

Tags: javascript, html, listview, windows-8, winjs

I am using WinJS.Binding.List() to bind Azure Mobile Service data to Listview.
How can I get the value and index of the selected from the listview?

```
//Javascript
var table = client.getTable('PatientInfo');
var birthCertData = function () {
            table.read().done(function (results) {
                   birthCert = new WinJS.Binding.List(results);
                   listItems.winControl.itemDataSource = birthCert.dataSource;
               });
        };

function selectionChangedHandler() {
//what should I type here to get the selectedCell Value and index?
        }

        listItems.addEventListener("selectionchanged", selectionChangedHandler, false);
```

This is my html

```
<div id="TemplateItem" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none">
   <div style="display: -ms-grid; -ms-grid-columns: auto 1fr">
      <div style="-ms-grid-column: 2; margin-left: 5px; height: 40px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
        <h3 data-win-bind="innerText: birthcert"></h3>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="listItems" class="win-selectionstylefilled" 
     data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
     data-win-options="{ itemTemplate: select('#TemplateItem'), 
     layout: {type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout}, 
     selectionMode: 'single', 
     tapBehavior: 'directSelect'}">
</div>

 <div style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 72px; -ms-grid-column: 2">
    <input type="text" id="textInput" />
 </div>
```

Screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di0BP.png

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the [selection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211852.aspx) property of the ListView

```
function selectionChangedHandler(e) {
    var numItemsSelected = listItems.selection.count;
    var indicesSelected = listItems.selection.getIndices();
    var itemsSelected = listItems.selection.getItems();
    ...

}
```

The [ISelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh872204.aspx) interface gives you the other options available to detect selection state. Note that the event's detail data (`e.detail`) will be null, so if you want to generically grab the source ListView, you can get to it via `e.srcElement`

Comment: Hi @Jim, meaning I should put in: 
var itemsSelected = listItems.selection.getItems(e.srcElement); ?

Comment: no, if you look at the code I pasted, that implementation will work only for the listItems DOM element. You wouldn't be able to use that same selectionChangedHandler for multiple different lists that might process different list views in the same way.  *IF* you wanted to have more reusable/generic code, you'd use e.srcElement to get a reference to the specific listView that caused the current firing of the event: something like e.srcElement.selection.getItems() (untested :))

Comment: Sorry @Jim, can you show me some generic code? 
I try to implement it but failed for few hours :(

the getItems() is undefined as expected. :(

Comment: sorry, forgot winControl in there... so if you pass the argument "e" to the selectionChanged handler, the specific listview involved will be at e.srcElement.winControl, and e.srcElement.winControl.selection.getItems() should work for you.  This time I tested it out :)  (using the [HTML ListView Essentials sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-basic-usage-sample-fcc451db))

Comment: Thank you so much @Jim.
Your hint helped me a lot! 
However getItems() return only object pair key/data pair for the specified list index, it does not return the value. 
However I tried different approach.
I used index = e.srcElement.winControl.selection.getIndices() to get the index of the listview of the selected item.
Then value.[key] = listview.getAt(index); to get the value.

Thank you so much.

Comment: doesn't getItems give you the actual object?

Comment: Hi Jim, getItems is parsing the object but the object can't parse the value, as that object return object key/data pair. Perhaps I am not sure how to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to the actual question, but may be helpful to you.
Currently, you are waiting for the entire contents of the WAMS table to be read and only then setting the datasource of the listview to be that entire read table.
I would suggest instead that you create a local WinJS.Binding.List, set the datasource of the listview to it immediately, and then when you read the WAMS table, iterate the resulting array and push the results into the Binding List.
The result will function identically to what you have, but it will be a bit better pattern and will allow a little bit of work to be done before the actual data call.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. with that, it really save me a lot of network resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function selectionChangedHandler(e) {

                // get the index of the selected listview item
                var index= e.srcElement.winControl.selection.getIndices();
                // get the object of the selected index
                var odata = birthcert.getAt(test);
                //odata.[key] is the value of the selected listview's item.

            }

            listItems.addEventListener("selectionchanged", selectionChangedHandler, false);
```